# Codeigniter global constant

Tags: codeigniter

I have defined one variable inside the `constants.php` file of codeigniter but i want to know how to use that variable into the view file.

```
define('UPLOAD_PATH', "/var/www/vhosts/dev/htdocs/p/");
```

I want to use 'UPLOAD_PATH' variable in my view file but i dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 11):

The same way you would use a constant in normal php?

```
echo UPLOAD_PATH; //would produce /var/www/vhosts/dev/htdocs/p/
```

So in your view file:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?=UPLOAD_PATH?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    config file (system/application/config/config.php) to set configuration related variables.

    Or use 

    constant file (system/application/config/constants.php) to store site preference constants.


  =======================
  DEFINE WHAT YOU WANT
  =======================
  $config['index_page'] = 'home';
  $config['BASEPATH'] = 'PATH TO YOUR HOST';
```